# What scripting language would you recommend for this task?

Tags: regex, automation

I want to implement a simple script to do some boring housekeeping on my media pc, but am not sure what scripting language would lend itself to this task.

Pseudocode for what I want to do is:

```
1) Scan a directory for sub directories matching a name like:

"Foo 1x01 bar"
"Foo 1x02 bar"
or 
"Foo s01e01 bar"
"Foo s01e02 bar"



2) Then for each matching sub directory:
  - Make a directory "Foo" if it doesn't already exist.
  - Copy the largest file under the matching sub directory into "Foo".
  - Delete the matched sub directory and anything left in it.
```

That's it. Although I might want to extend it to do more over time. Any suggestions for the most elegant scripting tool to use for this task?

Thanks

Comment: Using which operation system?

Comment: Cleaning up some downloads eh?

Comment: Yup :) - It's on Windows 7, but would be nice to be able to reuse on my mac also

Comment: I'd suggest python if you want to go cross-platform

Comment: I would recommend a VBScript.

Comment: Just pick a cross platform scripting language you're comfortable with: Perl, PHP, Python, Ruby, Tcl…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend Python, as you stated that you want to use it on your Mac too.
Using the the `shutil` and `os` modules (look at [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk)), it should be pretty easy. 
here's an example that gets the size of all of the files starting from the folder in the `top` variable.

```
import os
from os.path import join, getsize
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('python/Lib/email'):
    print root, "consumes",
    print sum(getsize(join(root, name)) for name in files),
    print "bytes in", len(files), "non-directory files"
    if 'CVS' in dirs:
        dirs.remove('CVS')  # don't visit CVS directories
```

Comment: This is a great starting point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell can easily do what you are looking for.  Check out [Microsoft's Script Center](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/).  It's got enough examples and tutuorials to bang this out pretty quickly.